# i was building my project using ANT ,but my build failed , i have tried debugging but no results

Tags: java, ant, build, erp

Following is the build out put , i have tried every thing even downloading      CompiereSecureDefault.properties  from internet and paste in the directory mentioned in output but it doesn't work . any suggestions?

Buildfile: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\utils_dev\build.xml

```
init:
    [echo] =========== Build Compiere - ${env.ENCODING}
    [echo] java.home    = D:\ProgramsandFiles\Java\jre6
    [echo] Java Version = 1.6.0_45 Sun Microsystems Inc.
    [exec] Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "svnversion" (in        directory "C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot     find the file specified
    [echo] =========== SVN Revision Core = ${svnoutput} 

build:

toolsInit:
    [echo] =========== Build Tools  ${env.COMPIERE_VERSION}

toolsCompile:

toolsServer:

toolsClient:

toolsAppsServer:

toolsDatabase:

toolsDistribution:

init:
    [echo] =========== Build Common

makedir:

compile:

dist:

initAD:
    [echo] =========== Build AD

compileAD:

distAD:

printInit:
    [echo] =========== Build Print

printMakedir:

printCompile:

printDistribute:

init:
    [echo] =========== Build Base

makedir:

compile:
   [javac] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\base\build

dist:

clientInit:
    [echo] =========== Build Client

clientMakedir:

clientCompile:

clientDistribute:
   [unjar] Expanding: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\common\Common.jar into     C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\client\build
   [unjar] Expanding: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\ad\AD.jar into C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\client\build
   [unjar] Expanding: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\base\Base.jar into C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\client\build
   [unjar] Expanding: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\print\Print.jar into C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\client\build
   [unjar] Expanding: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\interfaces\Interfaces.jar into C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\client\build
  [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\client\build\META-INF
     [jar] Building jar: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\lib\Compiere.jar
     [jar] Building jar: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\lib\CompiereInstall.jar

compiereRootInit:
    [echo] =========== Build Server Root

compiereRootXdoclet:
    [echo] XDoclet=../tools
    [echo] UpToDate=true
[ejbdoclet] Generating Home interface for 'org.compiere.session.ServerBean'.
[ejbdoclet] Generating Home interface for 'org.compiere.session.StatusBean'.
[ejbdoclet] Generating Local interface for 'org.compiere.session.ServerBean'.
[ejbdoclet] Generating Local interface for 'org.compiere.session.StatusBean'.
[ejbdoclet] Generating Local Home interface for 'org.compiere.session.ServerBean'.
[ejbdoclet] Generating Local Home interface for 'org.compiere.session.StatusBean'.
[ejbdoclet] Generating Remote interface for 'org.compiere.session.ServerBean'.
[ejbdoclet] Generating Remote interface for 'org.compiere.session.StatusBean'.
[ejbdoclet] Generating EJB deployment descriptor (ejb-jar.xml).

compiereRootCompile:
   [javac] Compiling 8 source files to    C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\serverRoot\build\classes

compiereRootJar:
     [jar] Building jar: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\serverRoot\build\deploy\compiereRoot.jar

compiereRootWar:
    [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\serverRoot\src\web
     [war] Building war: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\serverRoot\build\deploy\compiereRootBase.war
  [delete] Deleting: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\serverRoot\src\web\compiere.jnlp

wasCompiereRootWar:
    [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\serverRoot\src\web
     [war] Building war: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\serverRoot\build\deploy\compiereRootBase_was.war
  [delete] Deleting: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\serverRoot\src\web\compiere.jnlp

compiereRootInterfaces:
   [javac] Compiling 8 source files to C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\interfaces\classes
     [jar] Building jar: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\interfaces\Interfaces.jar

compiereRootDeployServer:
    [copy] Copying 3 files to C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\lib

main:

serverAppsInit:
    [echo] =========== Build Server Application

serverAppsCompile:

serverAppsJar:
     [jar] Building jar:    C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\serverApps\build\jar\compiereApps.jar

serverAppsWar:
     [war] Building war:  C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\serverApps\build\deploy\compiereAppsBase.war

serverAppsDeployServer:
    [copy] Copying 2 files to C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\lib

main:

init:
    [echo] =========== Build Web Store

war:
     [war] Building war:  C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\webStore\build\deploy\compiereWebStoreBase.war

deploy-server:
    [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\lib

main:

webCMinit:
    [echo] =========== Build webCM

webCMcompile:

webCMwar:
     [war] Building war:   C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\webCM\deploy\compiereWebCMbase.war

webCMdeployServer:
    [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\lib

main:

sqljInit:
    [echo] =========== Build SQLJ

sqljCompile:

sqljDist:
     [jar] Building jar: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\sqlj\sqlj.jar
     [jar] Building jar: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\sqlj\sqljDB2.jar

init:
    [echo] =========== Build Extend

makedir:

compile:

dist:
     [jar] Building jar: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\extend\Extend.jar
   [unjar] Expanding: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\lib\Compiere.jar into C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\extend\build
     [jar] Building jar: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\lib\Compiere.jar
     [jar] Warning: selected jar files include a META-INF/INDEX.LIST which will be    replaced by a newly generated one.

installInit:
    [echo] =========== Build Install - ${env.ENCODING}

installCompile:
   [unjar] Expanding: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\tools\lib\ant.jar into C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\install\lib
   [unjar] Expanding: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\tools\lib\ant-launcher.jar into C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\install\lib
   [unjar] Expanding: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\tools\lib\ant-commons-net.jar into C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\install\lib
   [unjar] Expanding: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\tools\lib\commons-net-1.4.0.jar into C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\install\lib
  [delete] Deleting: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\install\lib\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
     [jar] Building jar: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\install\CInstall.jar

installUpdate:

installDistribution:
    [copy] Copying 9 files to C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\install\build\Compiere2\lib
    [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\install\build\Compiere2\lib
    [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\install\build\Compiere2\lib
    [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\install\build\Compiere2\lib
     [zip] Building zip: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\install\build\Compiere_${env.COMPIERE_VERSION_FILE}.zip
     [tar] Building tar: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\install\build\Compiere_${env.COMPIERE_VERSION_FILE}.tar
    [gzip] Building: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\install\build\Compiere_${env.COMPIERE_VERSION_FILE}.tar.gz
  [delete] Deleting: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\install\build\Compiere_${env.COMPIERE_VERSION_FILE}.tar

install:
    [echo] =========== Install Compiere
    [copy] Copying 4 files to C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\${env.COMPIERE_INSTALL}
   [unzip] Expanding: C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\install\build\Compiere_${env.COMPIERE_VERSION_FILE}.zip into C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\${env.COMPIERE_ROOT}

setupInit:
    [echo] Compiere Server Setup ===================
    [echo] COMPIERE_HOME = D:\ProgramsandFiles\Compiere2
    [echo] Environment   = CompiereEnv.properties
    [echo] Java VM       = sun
    [echo] Database      = oracleXE
    [echo] Apps Server   = jboss
    [echo] AppsDeployment= D:\ProgramsandFiles\Compiere2\jboss\server\compiere\deploy
    [echo] Ant Version   = Apache Ant version 1.7.1 compiled on June 27 2008
    [echo] Java Home     = D:\ProgramsandFiles\Java\jre6
    [echo] Java Version  = 1.6.0_45 Sun Microsystems Inc.
    [echo] Windows=true JBoss=true Tomcat=${isAppsTomcat} WAS=${isIBMWAS}
    [echo] BaseJars=
    [echo] lib/ext= ${lib.ext.jar.exists}
    [echo] data/images= ${data.images.png.exists}

setupCompiere:

secureCopy:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\utils_dev\build.xml:78: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\ProgramsandFiles\Compiere2\build.xml:127: Warning: Could not find file        D:\ProgramsandFiles\Compiere2\lib\CompiereSecureDefault.properties to copy.
```

Total time: 8 minutes 57 seconds

Comment: I see you have references to C and D drives. Some of you build output seem to be redirected to folder on the C Drive and Some Build Executions seem to be directed from the D drive. I do not have enough info to look into you setup but I would advise you to redo/re-install/re-run and output everything on the C drive first and get that working there. Looks like something is messed up in your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you gave us a lot of information, but not what we really need. The error message is fine (we don't need the entire build output), but we don't have the relevant section of the `build.xml` that's failing.

I see the error:

```
C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\utils_dev\build.xml:78: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\ProgramsandFiles\Compiere2\build.xml:127: Warning: Could not find file \
D:\ProgramsandFiles\Compiere2\lib\CompiereSecureDefault.properties to copy.
```

It looks likes you're calling one build file from another. The error was reported to the build file in `utils_dev` which apparently called the one in `Compiere2`. On line #127 of that second `build.xml` file, you're doing some sort of `<copy/>` task, and you're specifying somehow that the file `lib/CompiereSecureDefault.properties` to be copied, but such a file does not exist.

You can do the following:

- Verify whether the file `Compiere2\lib\CompiereSecureDefault.properties` exist or doesn't exist.
- If it does not exist, why are you attempting to copy it? Should it be there?

I assume you're doing something like this:

```
<copy todir="${basedir}/blah/blah"
    file="${basedir}/lib/CompiereSecureDefault.properties"/>
```

You could change this to something like this:

```
<copy todir="${basedir}/blah/blah">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib">
         <include name="CompiereSecureDefault.properties"/>
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

The latter setup should not fail the build if that particular file cannot be found. (It will fail if the directory in the `<fileset dir="...">` does not exist.)

---

## Addendum:

> well u r right code which copies .properties file is following.

```
<target name="secureCopy" 
     unless="secure.exists"> 
     <copy file="lib/CompiereSecureDefault.properties" 
         tofile="lib/CompiereSecure.properties" overwrite="no" />
</target>
```

You could add:

```
<target name="secureCopy" 
     unless="secure.exists"> 
     <copy file="lib/CompiereSecureDefault.properties"
         failonerror="false"
         tofile="lib/CompiereSecure.properties" overwrite="no" />
</target>
```

However, a few more questions. What is the property `secure.exists`, and why is it not set? This task only executes if this property is **not** set.

Also, does that file exist? Is this the reason it's failing? Should it exist? You need to figure this out before adding the `failonerror` parameter.

Comment: well u r right code which copies .properties file is following.    <target name="secureCopy" unless="secure.exists">
  <copy file="lib/CompiereSecureDefault.properties" 
   tofile="lib/CompiereSecure.properties" overwrite="no" />
 </target>

Comment: yes i have the file but whenever i build source code ,file is  deleted from lib folder under d:/Compiere2/lib/ 
  BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Public\Compiere\Compiere\utils_dev\build.xml:78: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\ProgramsandFiles\Compiere2\build.xml:347: Error while expanding D:\ProgramsandFiles\Compiere2\lib\CCTools.jar
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\ProgramsandFiles\Compiere2\lib\CCTools.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Setting `failonerror` to `false` solve the issue? Do you need to _fix the build_ to prevent this file from being deleted (probably when a `clean` is done?